# Unable to test authentication in flask

Tags: flask, flask-security

I am trying to test a view which uses info from the current_user to create a model, store an instance of it and return a page with the model properties.
Unfortunately, I have problem in this view while working with the current_user. It seems that I cant simulate in the view the logging of an user because the view returns an AnonymousUser error (AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
).

How can I "fake" a logged user in the test so the test of the view passes?

Here a copy of the test and view

Thanks!

```
@api_blueprint.route('myurl', methods=['POST'])
def view():

    d = does_something(request.form)

    qo = models.Model(
        user=current_user, # HERE IS THE PROBLEM WITH THE LOGGING SINCE IN THE TEST IT IS AN AnonymousUser
        dump=d)
    )

    manager.session.add(qo)
    manager.session.commit()

    return render_template(
        'my_page.html',
    )

def test_view(self):
   query = {
        'foo': ['1', '2'],
    }

    self.login(test@example.com, password) # It seems it does not log an user but the test for this passed
    response = self.app.post(
        'myurl',
        data=query,
    )

def login(self, username, password):
    return self.app.post('/login', data=dict(
        username=username,
        password=password
 ), follow_redirects=True)
```

Comment: What authentication method are you using?

Comment: following the example of flask: def login(self, username, password):
        return self.app.post('/login', data=dict(
            username=username,
            password=password
), follow_redirects=True)

Comment: What example? Are you using a particular plugin?

Comment: The example from flask: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/testing/

Comment: The problem seems to be that it logs out after logging when I post the data to test the view it is already Anonymous user